# Determine the shortest possible match of a regular expression

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have an randomly ordered array of regular expressions like this:

```js
let patterns = [
    /foo+ba+r/,
    /foo/,
    /foo+bar/,
    /foobar/,
    /m[eo]{4,}w/,
    /boo/,
    /fooo*/,
    /meow/
]
```

I'm not sure if this is possible but I would like to write an algorithm which sorts the regular expressions from least greedy to most greedy, like this:

```js
[
    /foo/,
    /boo/,
    /fooo*/,
    /meow/,
    /foobar/,
    /foo+bar/,
    /m[eo]{4,}w/,
    /foo+ba+r/
]
```

I would imagine such sorting could be achieved like so:

```js
patterns.sort((p1, p2) { return p1.greediness() - p2.greediness() });
```

But there exists no method called `greediness` in the the `RegExpr` class.

Ideally, the `greediness` method would return the number of characters which could be possibly matched at minimum. i.e:

```js
/foo/.greediness() == 3
/boo/.greediness() == 3
/fooo*/.greediness() == 3
/meow/.greediness() == 4
/foobar/.greediness() == 6
/foo+bar/.greediness() == 6
/m[eo]{4,}w/.greediness() == 6
/foo+ba+r/.greediness() == 6
```

What would your solution be to this problem?

Comment: Seems like a pretty hard problem in general.

Comment: I would start by writing a function that takes a regex and returns a number based on a 'greediness' quotient.

Comment: `greediness()` could be easily extended within `RegEx.prototype`. Did you tried that ?

Comment: @aspirinemaga I don't assume the problem is *where to put* the implementaion (ie as an extension to to a prototype, or whatever) but the algorithm *how to calculate* the greediness ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is indeed a very difficult problem, which requires the ability to parse a regular expression (if the rules for regular expressions were reduced so that the only allowed input were "regular" characters and the special regex special characters `()[]|*+?`, constructing such a parser would not be too difficult). But given that you had such a parser, this would be my approach:

1. Convert the regular expression to a Nondeterministic Finite Automaton (NFA). This step is what requires a good regex parser but once you have that then the NFA construction is quite straight forward. Of course, if you can find a ready-made regular expression to NFA implementation, then that would be ideal.
2. Construct a directed, weighted graph representation of the NFA giving weight 1 to edges that represented a character transition and 0 to edges that  represented an epsilon transition.
3. Using Dijkstra's algorithm find the shortest path from the initial state of the NFA to the final state.

Let's take as an example the regex `m[eo]{2,}w`. Converted to a NFA with the appropriate edges marked with the weight above the edge and the character causing the state transition marked below the edge we get:

[image]

If an edge was defined by a length-3 array of elements consisting of `[from-state, to-state, weight]`, the array of edges for the above digraph would be:

```JavaScript
const edges = [
    [0, 1, 1],
    [1, 2, 0],
    [1, 3, 0],
    [2, 4, 1],
    [3, 5, 1],
    [4, 6, 0],
    [5, 6, 0],
    [6, 7, 0],
    [6, 8, 0],
    [7, 9, 1],
    [8, 10, 1],
    [9, 11, 0],
    [10, 11, 0],
    [11, 6, 0],
    [11, 12, 1]
];
```

Applying Dijkstra's algorithm to get the shortest path from state 0 to state 12 produces a length of 4 with the following path:

`0 -> 1 -> 3 -> 5 -> 6 -> 8 -> 10 -> 11 -> 12`

And thus the shortest string recognized by the regex would be 4.

So now all you need to do is find or code a JavaScript regular expression to NFA algorithm and a Dijkstra algorithm.

**Update**

If you are creating your own regex parser, then you can actually bypass creating the NFA and Dijkstra algorithm and compute the length instead. The following does not purport to be a full parser. For example, it does not support named group and it only recognized the basic "stuff."

```js
/*
  Grammar (my own extended BNF notation) where [token(s)]? denotes an optional token or tokens
  and [token(s)]+ denotes one or more of these tokens.

  E -> F E'
  E' -> '|' E
  F -> [SINGLE_CHAR FOLLOWER | '(' ['?:']? E ')' FOLLOWER]+ | epsilon
  SINGLE_CHAR -> CHAR | '[' BRACKET_CHARS ']'
  FOLLOWER -> EXPRESSION_FOLLOWER NON_GREEDY
  BRACKET_CHARS -> CHAR BRACKET_CHARS | epsilon
  EXPRESSION_FOLLOWER -> '*' | '+' | '?' | '{' number [',' [number]? '}' | epsilon
  NON_GREEDY -> '?' | epsilon
  */

  const EOF = 0;
  const CHAR = 1;

  let current_char;
  let current_token = null;
  let tokenizer;

  function* lexer(s) {
      // Produce next token:
      const single_character_tokens = '?*+{}[](),|';

      const l = s.length;
      let i = 0;
      while (i < l) {
          current_char = s[i++];
          if (single_character_tokens.indexOf(current_char) != -1) {
              // the current character is the token to yield:
              yield current_char;
          }
          else {
              if (current_char == '\\') {
                  if (i < l) {
                      current_char = s[i++];
                      if (current_char >= '0' && current_char <= '9') {
                          throw 'unsupported back reference';
                      }
                      if (current_char == 'b' || current_char == 'B') {
                          continue; // does not contribute to the length
                      }
                  }
                  else {
                      throw 'invalid escape sequence';
                  }
              }
              else if (current_char == '^' || current_char == '$') {
                  continue; // does not contribute to length
              }
              yield CHAR; // the actual character is current_char
          }
      }
      yield EOF;
  }

  function FOLLOWER() {
      // return a multiplier

      if (current_token === '?' || current_token === '*' || current_token === '+') {
          const l = current_token === '+' ? 1 : 0;
          current_token = tokenizer.next().value;
          if (current_token === '?') { // non-greedy
              current_token = tokenizer.next().value;
          }
          return l;
      }

      if (current_token === '{') {
          current_token = tokenizer.next().value;
          let s = '';
          while (current_token !== '}' && current_token !== EOF) {
              if (current_token === EOF) {
                  throw 'syntax error';
              }
              s += current_char;
              current_token = tokenizer.next().value;
          }
          current_token = tokenizer.next().value;
          const matches = s.match(/^(\d)+(,\d*)?$/);
          if (matches === null) {
              throw 'synatx error';
          }
          return parseInt(matches[0]);
      }

      return 1;
  }

  function F() {
      let l = 0;

      while (current_token == CHAR || current_char == '(' || current_char == '[') {
          if (current_token === CHAR || current_token === '[') {
              if (current_token == CHAR) {
                  current_token = tokenizer.next().value;
              }
              else {
                  current_token = tokenizer.next().value;
                  if (current_token == ']') {
                      current_token = tokenizer.next().value;
                      // empty []
                      FOLLOWER();
                      continue;
                  }
                  while (current_token != ']' && current_token != EOF) {
                      current_token = tokenizer.next().value;
                  }
                  if (current_token !== ']') {
                      throw 'syntax error';
                  }
                  current_token = tokenizer.next().value;
              }
              const multiplier = FOLLOWER();
              l += multiplier;
          }
          else if (current_token === '(') {
              current_token = tokenizer.next().value;
              if (current_token === '?') { // non-capturing group
                  current_token = tokenizer.next().value;
                  if (current_token !== CHAR || current_char !== ':') {
                      throw 'syntax error';
                  }
                  current_token = tokenizer.next().value;
              }
              const this_l = E();
              if (current_token !== ')') {
                  throw 'synatx error';
              }
              current_token = tokenizer.next().value;
              const multiplier = FOLLOWER();
              l += this_l * multiplier;
          }
          else {
              throw 'syntax error';
          }
      }

      return l;
  }

  function E() {
      let min_l = F();
      while (current_token === '|') {
          current_token = tokenizer.next().value;
          const l = F();
          if (l < min_l) {
              min_l = l;
          }
      }
      return min_l;
  }

  function parse(s) {
      tokenizer = lexer(s);
      current_token = tokenizer.next().value;
      const l = E();
      if (current_token !== EOF) {
          throw 'syntax error';
      }
      return l;
  }

  let patterns = [
    new RegExp(''),
    /(?:)[]()/,
    /abc|$/,
    /^foo+ba+r$/,
    /foo+ba+r/,
    /foo/,
    /foo+bar/,
    /foobar/,
    /m([eo]{4,})w/,
    /m(?:[eo]{4,})w/,
    /boo/,
    /fooo*/,
    /meow/,
    /\b\d+\b/
  ];


  RegExp.prototype.greediness = function () {
    return parse(this.source);
  };


  let prompt_msg = 'Try your own regex wihout the / delimiters:';
  while (true) {
      const regex = prompt(prompt_msg);
      try {
          console.log(`You entered '${regex}' and its greediness is ${new RegExp(regex).greediness()}.`);
          break;
      }
      catch (error) {
          prompt_msg = `Your input resulted in ${error}. Try again:`;
      }
  }

  console.log('\nSome tests:\n\n');
  for (const pattern of patterns) {
      console.log(`pattern = ${pattern.source}, greediness = ${pattern.greediness()}`);
  }
```

Comment: This is a great idea.  And unlike my suggestion, it makes it clear how to deal with capturing groups.  It still leaves the hard part of actually writing such a parser, but with all the regex explanation tools available -- and the fact that JS engines themselves have to parse the regex string -- this is something you might be able to find.  The syntax tree -> DFA code should be relatively straightforward.  Very nice!

Comment: @ScottSauyet If you can find code that creates a DFA, which is a more complicated algorithm, that works also. But even if you only have an NFA, you simply apply weight 0 to the epsilon transitions.

Comment: Sorry, typo.  I meant NFA, of course.  No reason to go to a DFA.  We know they're equivalent -- one of my all-time favorite proofs! -- but an NFA will be much, much easier here.

Comment: This is a great answer. I expanded on this and generated an AST for [my implementation](https://ideone.com/2cikZd).

Comment: I am glad you found the answer useful. By the way, I  just updated the code snippet slightly because I just realized I wasn't handling the backslash character.

Answer (score 3):

As Pointy said in the comments, this is a hard problem.

Here is the beginning of a solution:

```js
const greediness = (s) =>
  s .toString () .slice (1, -1)
    .replace (/\[[^\]]+]/g, 'X')
    .replace (/.\{((\d+)(,\d*))\}/g, (s, a, ds, _) => 'X' .repeat (Number (ds)))
    .replace (/.\+/g, 'X')
    .replace (/.\?/g, '')
    .replace (/.\*/g, '')
    .length

const sortByGreediness = (patterns) =>
  [...patterns] .sort ((a, b) => greediness (a) - greediness (b))
    // .map (s => [s, greediness (s)])  // to show sizes


const patterns = [/foo+ba+r/, /foo/, /foo+bar/, /foobar/, /m[eo]{4,}w/, /boo/, /fooo*/, /meow/]


console .log (sortByGreediness (patterns))
```

We simply take the text of the regex and replace quantifiers and their preceding characters with the smallest number of characters that might match.  We do something similar for blocks like `[eo]` and `X{4,}`.

This we might go through steps like this:

```
m[eo]{4,}wp+u+r?r*
mX{4,}wp+u+r?r*
mXXXXwp+u+r?r*
mXXXXXwXr?r*
mXXXXXwXr*
mXXXXXwX
  - length 7
```

But this doesn't touch on the complexities that can be inside a regex, and doesn't even try to handle capturing groups.  I think it would next to impossible to do for the full regex spec, but perhaps this can be expanded toward what you need.

(If you're getting more complex, you might want to do this repeatedly with code something like the following, or with a `while` loop in place of its recursion.

```js
const greediness = (s, next = s .toString () .slice (1, -1), prev = null) =>
  next === prev
    ? next .length
    : greediness (s, next
        .replace (/\[[^\]]+]/g, 'X')
        .replace (/.\{((\d+)(,\d*))\}/g, (s, a, ds, _) => 'X' .repeat (Number (ds)))
        .replace (/.\+/g, 'X')
        .replace (/.\?/g, '')
        .replace (/.\*/g, '')
      , next)
```